# add onclick function to a column cells

Tags: javascript

I have a auto generate table that inserts cells to table like this

```
window.addEventListener('load', function() {

web3.eth.getAccounts().then((acco) =>{

    for(var i = 0 ; i <= lenght ; i++){
    myContract.methods.contractmanager(acco[0] , i).call().then((res)=>{
  var table = document.getElementById("tb");
  var row = table.insertRow(i + 1);
  var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
  var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
  var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
  var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
  var cell5 = row.insertCell(4);
  var cell6 = row.insertCell(5);
  cell1.innerHTML = res[0];
  cell2.innerHTML = res[1];
  cell3.innerHTML = res[2];
  cell4.innerHTML = res[3];
  cell5.innerHTML = res[4];
  cell6.innerHTML = res[5];
});
}
});
});
```

it takes data from smart contract and every object creates a row
i want to first column be clickable and every time i click on each cell of column i want to execute a function with data in the cell

Comment: the simpliest way  is event delegation

Comment: how to add it to a column with random number of cells?

Comment: your question is really incomplete, why only give this additional information second? are there any other surprises?  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: sorry it was my first time and no other surprises and if you can help me with that i would happy

Comment: in this case explain how your columns are, because in html each row must have the same number of columns, allowing some to overlap more than one column. but it can't be random, so still need more explanation

Comment: i just edited my question

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can add event ont the first cell using `addEventListener('click')`

You can then display what you want using this event.

```js
const data = [
  [1, 2, 3, 4],
  [5, 6, 7, 8],
  [9, 10, 11, 12],
  [13, 14, 15, 16],
]

var table = document.getElementById("tb");

for (let res of data) {
  var row = table.insertRow(1);
  var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
  var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
  var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
  var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);

  cell1.innerHTML = res[0];

  cell1.addEventListener('click', function() {
    console.log("You clicked on the first cell")
    console.log(res)
    //do what you want 
  })

  cell2.innerHTML = res[1];
  cell3.innerHTML = res[2];
  cell4.innerHTML = res[3];
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <table id="tb">
    <tbody>
      <tr></tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: my table has more than one row so i have more than one cell in my column and i want to make them clickable and do a function depend on cells data

Comment: Just edited my answer, tell me if it helps. Otherwise, I guess I haven't understand well the question.

Comment: thx for your help but it doesnt work for like 10 cells in a column it just works for first cell can you help me with that?

Comment: Here, i just added an event Listener on the first cell of every row. If you want to add an eventListener on every cell, just add `cell2.addEventListener`, `cell3.addEventListener`,...

Answer (score 0):

you should try `addEventListener` like below.

```js
    var res = [
      [5, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1, 2],
      [6, 7, 1, 1, 9, 5, 3, 4, 8],
      [1, 9, 2, 3, 4, 2, 5, 6, 7],
      [8, 5, 9, 7, 6, 1, 4, 2, 3],
      [4, 2, 6, 5, 5, 3, 7, 9, 1],
      [7, 1, 3, 1, 2, 4, 8, 5, 6],
      [9, 6, 1, 5, 3, 7, 2, 8, 4],
      [2, 8, 7, 5, 1, 9, 6, 3, 5],
      [3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 6, 1, 7, 9]
    ];
    var table = document.getElementById("tb");
    for(let i = 0; i < res.length; i ++){
      var row = table.insertRow(i);
      for(let j = 0; j < res[i].length; j ++){
        var cell = row.insertCell(j);
        cell.innerHTML = res[i][j];
        cell.addEventListener("click",function(){ 
        console.log(`this is %d's row and %d's column and value is %s`, i + 1, j + 1, res[i][j])
        });}
    }
```

```html
    <table id="tb" border="1">
    </table>
```

Comment: my table has more than one row so i have more than one cell in my column and it auto generate and i want to make them clickable and do a function depend on cells data

Answer (score 0):

the way to  do that

```js
const tableData = 
  [ [ 5, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8 ]
  , [ 6, 7, 1, 1, 9, 5 ]
  , [ 1, 9, 2, 3, 4, 2 ]
  , [ 8, 5, 9, 7, 6, 1 ]
  , [ 4, 2, 6, 5, 5, 3 ]
  , [ 7, 1, 3, 1, 2, 4 ]
  , [ 9, 6, 1, 5, 3, 7 ]
  , [ 2, 8, 7, 5, 1, 9 ]
  , [ 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 6 ]
  ]

const myTableBody = document.querySelector('#my-table')

tableData.forEach(res=>
  {
  let newRow = myTableBody.insertRow()  
  res.forEach(c=> newRow.insertCell().textContent = c ) 
  })

myTableBody.onclick = ({target}) => // event delegation system
  {
  if (!target.matches('td:nth-of-type(1)')) return // ignore oother clicks

  let row     = target.closest('tr')
    , colVals = Array.from({length:6},(_,i)=>row.cells[i].textContent).join() 
    ; 
  console.clear()
  // console.log( 'row values', target.closest('tr').innerText )
  console.log( 'row values', colVals )
  }
```

```css
table  {
  border-collapse : collapse;
  margin          : 2em 1em;
  }
td {
  padding    : .2em .8em;
  border     : 1px solid darkblue;
  }
td:nth-of-type(1) {
  cursor : pointer;
  }
td:nth-of-type(1):hover {
  background-color: aqua;
  }
```

```html
<table id="my-table"></table>
```